# Middle 3 Characters of name

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, substring

I need help on finding the middle 3 letters of a name in c# string manipulation, my code is:

```
int len=propName.length;

StringName middle3 = (len < 3) ? null : propName.substring(len / 2, len / 2 + 2);
```

And it returns the middle 3 letters for certain names, but if I add a longer name, it doesn't work. Here name comes from a TextBox input control.

Also some names have even numbers, and not all names have 5, 7 or 9 letters, what should I do in this cases?

Comment: Please show a full example that reproduces the problem, for example by adding `string propName = "name";` and explaining what you would like to see in those cases. It really helps to write a few examples on paper.

Comment: There is absolutely not enough information here to answer this question.

Comment: Alright, I'm creating an asp.net web application, in my btn I declared String name=txtName.Text; and passed my values to my class which will perform the string manipulation. My method is public String generatemiddle3() nd it has a return method. If the user inputs Abdul, the program needs to output bdu , or if the user inputs Govendr it needs to output ven. But for a name like Riyadh, how could it output the middle 3? What would happen?

Comment: What would you class as the middle three in `Riyadh` seeing as there is no clean middle - `iya` or `yad`?

Comment: **Riyadh** - which 3 letters do you want to see in this case?

Comment: I would say yad? Should I create an IF statement for dat? And why is my code extracting the middle 3 of selected lengths of names? Like if I input a name that's 5letters, it outputs correctly but for 7 or 9 its uncorrect

Comment: @ReeDee99, please see my answer. I believe it should work as you want.

Comment: Thats due to the second part of your substring - it should say **3** instead of **len/2+2**.

Answer (score 2):

If you are inputting a 'full' name (this example will get the middle three characters of their middle name):

1. if the full name is in the format of `First Middle Last`, use the `Split()` method to split on the '`space`' between them
2. Get length of the string value within the 1st index
3. Check the middle index is longer than 3 characters. If so, proceed. if not, return whole string
4. get the three middle characters using the `myThree.Substring((len/2)-1,3)` to get the neext three letters.

If you only have a single-name (such as 'James' or 'Stacey' etc)

```
String name = "James";
name = name.Replace(' ',''); //removes spaces (if any entered)
int len = string.Length;
if(len%2 ==0)
{
  //then it is an even number 
 len--; //if you want the 'slightly' left-er part. Else remove this if statement
}
if(len>=3)
{
String myThree = myThree.Substring(len-1,3);
}
else
{
   if(len==0)
   {
      Messagebox.Show("No name entered");
   }
   else
   {
    myThree= name;
   }
}
```

Any suggestions/clarification needed I'll be glad to help.

Comment: According to your point 4, you probably meant `myThree.Substring((len/2)-1,3)`.

Comment: @Corak I did, indeed. cheers

Comment: Thank you soooo much MrCoder, and Corak, really appreciate the help, I most definitely will. Thanks again

Comment: if this works/helped you, please remember to help others by accepting it as an anser (clicking on the tick on the left) ;P